# Update entity that is not part of the client collection

Tags: meteor

I am trying to update related entities when deleting an entity. The problem is that the related entities are not part of the collection on the client. Is there a way to do the update only on the server?

Concrete example: When calling 'removeSlack', I want to update all the copies and remove the removed slackId from their copies array. But because the copies are not part of the collection on the client 'Slack.findOne(copyId)' doesn't find anything.

```
Meteor.methods(
  removeSlack: (slackId) ->
    slack = Slack.findOne(slackId)
    for copyId in _.pluck(slack.copies, 'slackId')
      copy = Slack.findOne(copyId)
      if copy
        Slack.update(copyId, { $set: {copies: _.without(copy.copies, {slackId: slackId, userId: Meteor.userId()})}})
    Slack.remove(slackId)
)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can wrap any code you only want to run on the server in a Meteor.isServer() block: http://docs.meteor.com/#meteor_isserver

Alternatively, you can put code files you only want to run on the server in the /server folder of your project.

Comment: So it turns out that the problem wasn't that the update wasn't executed, but that _.without uses object equality and I expected deep comparison like _.isEqual does. Using (c for c in copy.copies when not _.isEqual(c, {slackId: slackId, userId: Meteor.userId()})) instead of the _.without part fixed it.